# How to pass database name into stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to pass database name into stored procedure? I tried something like

```
create procedure dbo.Test
    @databaseName varchar(100)
as
select * from @databasename.Person.Address
go
```

I would like to use it like this

```
execute dbo.Test @databaseName = 'AdventureWorks'
```

Comment: DB_NAME() gives you the current database. You dont need to write a procedure for that. DB_NAME() does the same job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in the manner you are describing.

You can do this with [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), but that brings its own set of problems.

Comment: You can *only* do it with dynamic SQL either assembled in the db or outside.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to move information which should be part of connection string into stored procedure logic. If you expect that Person table will be in different database this database name should be fixed in deployment - for example by parametrized creation script and sqlcmd.